# How to check the type of data inside a Pytorch tensor?

Tags: types, pytorch, tensor

I know that I can access the type of the data a tensor by doing `Tensor.dtype`.

I also know that I can check whether an object is of a certain type by using `isinstance`.

How can I check with an `if` statement whether my Tensor contains a specific type of data, say `ComplexFloat` ? I am looking for a "pythonic" way, like using the `isinstance` function

Answer (score 0):

All elements of your tensor will share the same data type, the one given to your tensor on initialization or after casting.

PyTorch supports three [complex data types](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#data-types):

- 32-bit complex: `torch.complex32` or `torch.chalf`
- 64-bit complex: `torch.complex64` or `torch.cfloat`
- 128-bit complex: `torch.complex128` or `torch.cdouble`

Based on that, you can check and compare your tensor's data type (`Tensor.dtype`) with:

```
if x.dtype in [torch.chalf, torch.cfloat, torch.cdouble]:
    pass
```

Comment: What I mean is that during my training, based on which options I set in the beginning, my tensor may end up containing either floats, or ComplexFloat. I want to do something only if the tensor contains ComplexFloat

Comment: Is there a more "pythonic" way using `isinstance` ?

Comment: You can't use `isinstance` because it will check for the instance class of your object, i.e. `torch.Tensor`, whereas you are looking to check its data type (the type of its underlying data values).